# Changing contents of Char *

Tags: c

My code is like this

```
Char * q = "Bye";
strcpy (&q[1], "K");
```

When I compile it, it starts hanging. I am using in MinGW in Windows 7.
Even if I allocate `malloc` to `q`, the problem persists

If i try to assign `q[1]= 'K'`, then also it hangs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string initialized with "char \*s" but not "char s\[\]"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha)

Comment: The code hangs at compilation?

Comment: You're not trying to change the contents of a `char*`. If you were, it would be `q = something;`. You're actually trying to change the contents of the thing it points to.

Comment: But your code won't even compile!

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize a char pointer with a string literal the compiler may store the string in read-only memory. If you really want to have the string be modifiable then try storing it on the local stack:

```
Char q[]="Bye";
```